# Twitter Boostrap control div not aligning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a quick Bootstrap issue. I am setting up a form and it seems that the form label is not aligning to the input field. I have had an issue like this before which was solved by adding clearfix to the class. This did not resolve the issue.

Fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/P6ux2/1/

```
<div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="well">
        <label class="control-label" for="interview">Label 1</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="interview" name="FDFINTERVIEW" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="resume">Label 2</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="resume" name="FDFMEMOSENT" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="memoreceived">Label 3</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="memoreceived" name="FDFMEMORECV" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="selectionemail">Label 4</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="selectionemail" name="fdfEmailSent" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="fdfSECSbmt">Label 5</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="fdfSECSbmt" name="fdfSECSbmt" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="fdfInSECGrnt">Label 6</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="fdfInSECGrnt" name="fdfInSECGrnt" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="fdfInSECDeny">Label 1=7</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="fdfInSECDeny" name="fdfInSECDeny" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="fdfFullSECGrnt">Label 8</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="fdfFullSECGrnt" name="fdfFullSECGrnt" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="fdfMEDGrnt">Label 9</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="fdfMEDGrnt" name="fdfMEDGrnt" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="fdfEOD">Label 10</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="fdfEOD" name="fdfEOD" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="textarea">Label 11</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea class="input-xlarge" id="textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of well -->
</div>
```

TIA

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about how exactly you want it to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the element in a `control-group` class and add to your form the `form-horizontal` class, you also don't need an extra div for your input.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="interview">Label 1</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="interview" name="FDFINTERVIEW" class="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

> - Add `.form-horizontal` to the form.
> - Wrap labels and controls in `.control-group`
> - Add `.control-label` to the label
> - Wrap any associated controls in `.controls` for proper alignment
>
> [Twitter Bootstrap doc](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) - Horizontal Form

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I did just try what you suggested and I still get the same results. I copied and pasted the exact line of code and it still is not aligned. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh.. that works much better Thanks for the time and effort. It's appreciated!!